# Visual Studio ASP XML web.config transform wrapping lines

Tags: web.config-transform

Does anyone know how to make the transform in VS 2017 not add line breaks?

My transform code

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <endpoint address="http://*********/HierarchicalView.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView" contract="HierarchicalViewServiceReference.IHierarchicalView" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView" />
```

This line

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:64707/HierarchicalView.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView" contract="HierarchicalViewServiceReference.IHierarchicalView" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView" />
```

becomes this in my transform

```
 <endpoint address="http://*********/HierarchicalView.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView" contract="HierarchicalViewServiceReference.IHierarchicalView"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IHierarchicalView"/>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but wanted to ask if you figured it out. Having this same issue.

Comment: everyone suggests setting up SlowCheetah. i didnt want the hassle and gave up